# How do I speed up Windows Vista 64 for use with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, performance, windows-vista

I am aware that I may be asking this in the wrong place.  If so, mods - please point me in the right direction.

Anyway, I'm sure that you guys have faced this problem.  I have 6 gigs of RAM and VS makes my machine crawl.  This doesn't always happen.  I've made sure that no other major, non-required processes are running other than a Chrome window, VS 2008 and occasionally Reflector.

I have Resharper installed, and I've turned off the Solution-wide analysis.  I have one solution open.

This issue is really killing my productivity.  It takes up to a minute to switch files.

**EDIT:**  I have about fifteen projects in the current solution but no more than six are loaded at a time.  I am running the most updated version of VS2008

Comment: How many files and projects do you have in your solution?

Comment: Make sure you're running SP2 of Windows Vista x64, + any hotfixes that Windows Update'll give you.

Comment: Have you tried looking into ProcessMonitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really say what exactly is crawling.

I would guess it is disk access causing the problem. If you happen to be using a laptop with a power-saving 5,400 RPM disk then it's almost certainly the problem. Those drives suck. A lot.

Snowbear had a good suggestion of using a RAM drive for your files. The tricky part is remembering to always copy your changes to hard disk.

Another good idea is using an SSD drive. A second good idea is RAID-0 hard disks, either Western Digital Velociraptors or SCSI 15k's.

Upgrading your hard disks won't just speed up Visual Studio. It'll make a difference to your whole computer experience. I really recommend the SSD option.

Comment: I have a laptop.  How do I determine if it meets that criteria (5400rpm disk)?

Answer (score 3):

With such an amount of RAM I would use RamDrive - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_disk
It may help if your performance degrades due to some problems with hard drive.